# don't change object after passing function

Tags: javascript, object, constants

```
myObject = {foo: foo, bar: bar}

function myFunc(obj){
    obj.foo = 'new foo';
}

myFunc(myObject); {foo: 'new foo', bar: bar}
```

Why is myObject changed? I don't want to change it

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: If you don't want to change it... don't change it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the object is being passed by reference. If you dont want a function to modify the input argument, you can make a deep copy of the object before passing it to the function. Or better yet, [write pure functions as much as possible – without any side effects.](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pure_function)

```
myObject = {foo: foo, bar: bar}

function myFunc(obj){
    obj.foo = 'new foo';
}

myFunc(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define `foo` property under `myObject` as follows.

```
Object.defineProperty(myObject, 'foo', {   
  value: '<value u want to put for this object>'
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
});
```

The `configurable` attribute tells whether the property can be deleted and its attributes (other than writable) can be changed.

The `writable` attribute tells whether the property value can be changed or not.